# How to record video from webcam in a lossless format?

Tags: java, video, webcam, xuggler, xuggle

I'm trying to write an application which can record video in a lossless format. For this purpose I use Webcam-Capture and Xuggler libraries. Everything works but the outout video has the following artifacts: [image]

And this is observed not at all frames, nearly 1 of 5 ones. My code:

```
@FXML
public void record() {
            File file = new File("output.wmv");

            IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(file.getName());
            Dimension size = WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize();

            writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, size.width, size.height);

            Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
            webcam.setViewSize(size);
            webcam.open(true);

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

                System.out.println("Capture frame " + i);

                BufferedImage image = ConverterFactory.convertToType(webcam.getImage(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);

                IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(image, (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000);
                frame.setKeyFrame(i == 0);
                frame.setQuality(100);

                writer.encodeVideo(0, frame);

                // 10 FPS
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
            }

            writer.close();

            System.out.println("Video recorded in file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Needs more information on your dependencies.  Links maybe?

Comment: What links exactly you need?